# How to read different data from the same .dat file without creating parameter list for each field in load runner?

Tags: loadrunner, vugen

I have three fields in the application. I want to create one test data file (.dat) file containing 3 data for each field. I don't want to create a new Parameter list for each field.

[image]dat file is TestData

TestData has the following information

Username,Address,DOB

XYZ,102,25

Comment: Excellent pre-hire programming question to see the maturity of your skills in breaking apart a line based upon a common field separator

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create 3 different parameter files!
Create the 3 parameters, and point them all to the same `.dat` file (You can do this by setting the file name in the "File Path" textbox).

Set one of the parameters as `Uniqe` / `Random` / `Sequential`, and the other 2, set them as `Same line as <Parameter 1 name>`.
This will cause the other 2 parameter always to be taken from the same line as the 1st parameter, linking them, and correlating them in run-time.